# PHP Form Mail - implode function returning error

Tags: php, email, implode

My form is working but I am seeing the following error in my scripts.log file

> PHP Warning:  implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Here is my HTML:

```
        <td><select name="additional_events[]" size="8" multiple="multiple" class="formFields">
 <option selected></option><?php echo $drop_down_list;?> 
    </select></td>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$additional_events = trim(stripslashes(implode("  ///  ", $_POST['additional_events'])));
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What do you see when you `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Is additional events an array?  Probably not since its posted.

Comment: by defining name=additional_events[] in the html, does that turn it into an array?